# css property for variable in id

Tags: php, html, css

I have 5 links in different row in a div like:
   A
   B
   C
   D
   E
now i set id variable for the row, now is it possible to set css in the row id variable.here is my code:

```
<div class='cusine_list'>    
     <ul>
         <?php    
               $i = 0;
               foreach($cuisines as $key=>$cuisine): ?>

                   <li id='cl-<?php echo $i?>' class="lc" onclick="changeRowColor($(this).attr('id'));">
                        <a href="<?php echo $this->webroot?>restaurants/index?cusine=<?php echo $key?>"><?php echo $cuisine?></a>                                
                 </li>  
               <?php  $i++; endforeach; ?>  

      </ul>                   
 </div>
```

here i want to set css for variable i in the cl id, how can i do it ?

actually my problem is , when i click a link it changes background color of the selected link but it changes again when the page is loaded, but i want, it will be  unchanged after loading the page, how can i do it ?

here is my scripting code;

```
  <script>
         function changeRowColor(id)
         {

            $('.lc').css('background-color', '#E2E2D4');
            $("#"+id).css({"background-color":"#33AD5C"});

         };
  </script>
```

Comment: Just set it normally as you are already doing with other attributes?

Comment: don't make it more complicated, just use classes